# Can resources in an Android APK-file be changed without rebuilding?

Tags: java, android, apk

In My android application i only need to make a small change in a property file.

For example:

In my property file ,there is a welcome message for specific client.
So,i have to change only client name in my application.

But the problem is ,I have to do that in source and then have to build every time for every client.

Is there any way to change it directly in **.apk** file without creating a build again & again.

Comment: because every client want its own name in application

Comment: I know that. Why would you want to avoid a rebuild? Are you compiling skynet or something?

Comment: because apart from single text there is no change........And the system team at client end has to wait for me, i want that they can make the change without my dependency

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To do this, you will have to decompress the packaged APK, and find the string you want to changed. The string may have been encoded or converted to bytecode (Java String) or a binary format (XML String). You will need to figure out whether or not this has been done, and what the new String looks like. You will then need to take the string you want to replace it with, and encode it the same way before swapping them.

After you've done all this, you must recompress the app and run the signing tool and zip align manually before it is usable in an apk format again.

Quite frankly, it'll take you longer to do this than to just recompile the app.

Comment: +1 for clearly explaining the hassle in messing up the binary.

Comment: apart from rebuild there is no other easier way that even non developers can do....

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Android APK Tool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/).

To quote the description

> It is a tool for reverse engineering 3rd party, closed, binary Android
>   apps. It can decode resources to nearly original form and rebuild them
>   after making some modifications;

Answer (score 1):

Since you own the source code, unpacking and rebuilding the APK seems to be a waste of time. You should solve this problem in the original build process.

If you building your APK-packages manually with Eclipse, then you should look into setting up some automated build system (Ant, Maven, etc.) and provide the client name as a parameter to the build script.

If you are already using Ant or Maven, then those tools already provide methods for replacing a tag in a text file with a property value before compiling. Please tell us more about your build environment so that we can give more accurate answers.

Comment: currently i am using manual way in eclipse. can u provide more detail on "how to use ant for creating .apk file"

Comment: As per StackOverflow rules, you need to Google that and create a new question with specifics once you have the basic understanding about the subject. The Google keywords are "android ant build".